# Google Maps API Key works in Release version when side loaded, does not work when published

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api, google-play-console

I have an app that uses the Maps API, I have a Debug and Release key for the API.  This all works great when side loaded.  The Release key works with the release build.  I uploaded the Release APK to the Google Play Console and pushed out an Internal Test release.  I installed from the store and it acts like the API key is no good.

I have gone through a number of similar problems here on the site and even tried hard coding the release key in the manifest and in all cases it works fine when side loaded but not when installed through the Google Play Store.

I hooked the phone up to a log analyzer and did a number of map operations to try and see what the problem is, but the only two messages I got in the log indicated that the Map API was working even though I had no Map displaying and it acted like the API key was missing or invalid.  Note, the deprecation warning occurred when I changed from standard to satellite, I am not using indoor support directly.  The API package version message occurred when the Activity loaded.

Here are the two log entries:
02-03 09:23:07.550 15809-15809/? W/Google Maps Android API: Deprecation notice: In a future release, indoor will no longer be supported on satellite, hybrid or terrain type maps. Even where indoor is not supported, isIndoorEnabled() will continue to return the value that has been set via setIndoorEnabled(), as it does now. By default, setIndoorEnabled is 'true'. The API release notes (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/releases) will let you know when indoor support becomes unavailable on those map types.

02-03 09:30:24.319 15809-15809/? I/Google Maps Android API: Google Play services package version: 14799019

I am using the Google Signing and have the signing keys uploaded, I thought it might be getting double signed and causing a problem.  I uploaded an unsigned APK and the Google Play Console took the app and signed it.  I also uploaded signed APKs and in either case the map is blank and acts like there is no key or the key is invalid.  In all cases the map works just fine when side loaded, i.e. not through the store, but didn't display the map when loaded through the store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

as it sounds, you have to add the fingerprint of the *actual* "release key" (called "app signing key" in the scheme shown) to the restrictions of the used Maps API key. the "upload key" is something else, when it comes to v2 signing (this is the one key fingerprint most likely used when side-loaded). to have that 1 Maps API key working under any condition, it should have 3 key fingerprints added.

[image: v2 app signing]

image source: [documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#app-signing-google-play).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was missing.  I went to the screen in the console and added the signing key.  The developer signs it with the upload key which is why it worked when side loaded.

Comment: Guys thanks so much for this! I have been ripping my hair of over why this don't work for me, had the exact same problem. This solution worked for med aswell!

Comment: Thaanks... i had no clue what's wrong !!
For easier approach navigate to google play console > your app > Setup > app integrity.
there you'll find your "App signing key certificate" and "Upload key certificate" SHA-1... add both to maps API ;)

Answer (score 3):

Are you enrolled in App Signing by Google Play with an upload key? If so, Google Play re-signs your APK before releasing it to users, which would explain why it works locally but not when published through Play.

You can verify if you're enrolled by going to the App Signing page in the Play Console. If you are, then you'll need to whitelist the app signing certificate in the credentials section of the Google Maps API of the Cloud Console.

You can read more about App Signing at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423

Comment: You both got the correct answer, unfortunately I can only select one as the answer and the other answer had more details and more votes.

Comment: @Scott they were also posted at almost the same time; will up-vote.